# Is "extreme CVaR" (CVaR from extreme value theory) elicitable or conditionally elicitable with some other statistical mapping (like VaR)?

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, optimization, risk-models

I am not able to find loss function (scoring function) extreme CVaR (CVaR from extreme value theory) which is a conditionally elicitable statistical mapping (conditioned on VaR).
In this regard, can someone help me!! Where I should look for it.

Comment: How is this opinion based?

Comment: I think, this is not an opinion based question, it can be answered with facts and citations!!